# Android how to use BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL to a mask bitmap in Canvas

Tags: android

I have a mask bitmap with alpha channel,I want use it to cover origin bitmap and **make sure edge feather**.I try to use below code,but failed:

```
AndroidManifest.xml:android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

fun featherEdge(maskBm: Bitmap): Bitmap {
        if (maskBm == null) return maskBm
        val canvasBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(maskBm.width, maskBm.height, ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(canvasBmp)
//        canvas.isHardwareAccelerated = false
        val paint = Paint()
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        paint.isDither = true
        paint.maskFilter = BlurMaskFilter(20f, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
        canvas.drawBitmap(maskBm, 0f, 0f, paint)
        return canvasBmp
    }
```

result bitmap edge is rough:
[image]
what I want result:
[image] 
Question2:
Because `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`,many function can't work,how to make `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` only to off-Screen canvas?
Thank you.